# Convert from VARCHAR2 to NCLOB (oracle)

Tags: oracle, varchar2, nclob

I got a column message with data_type = VARCHAR2. It already has some data stored. I want this column to be of type NCLOB. Code-Set for this column should be UTF-8.

I did the following:

- added a column `tempmessage` to my table of type NCLOB
- filled `tempmessage` with message
- renamed message to message old (so that i don't use any data (until it works))
- renamed `tempmessage` to message

Then i tried out my integration tests and i got the exception:
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-01400: Insert of NULL into ("BATCH_LOG"."MESSAGEOLD") not possible.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The original column was defined as `NOT NULL`, when you renamed that to `MESSAGEOLD`, this constraint was kept. You need to remove the NOT NULL constraint from the `MESSAGEOLD` column:

```
ALTER TABLE foo MODIFY MESSAGEOLD NULL;
```